# Yelp PHP API Issues

Tags: php, api, curl, yelp

I am running php 7.2.24 and testing the Yelp PHP sample have noticed that it produces no results but errors. The code was written 6 years ago, so not sure if it is an outdated code issue or perhaps using the wrong version of PHP.

Error is the following: Fatal error: Curl failed with error #400: {"error": {"code": "VALIDATION_ERROR", "description": "'Bearer' does not match '^(?i)Bearer [A-Za-z0-9\\-\\_]{128}$'", "field": "Authorization", "instance": "Bearer"}}

Yelp PHP code link -> https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-fusion/tree/master/fusion/php

Guidance is greatly appreciated.

Diego

====== MY CODE BELOW ======

```
 <?php

 $API_KEY = 'My_Yelp_API_Key';

// Complain if credentials haven't been filled out.
assert($API_KEY, "Please supply your API key.");

// API constants, you shouldn't have to change these.
$API_HOST = "https://api.yelp.com";
$SEARCH_PATH = "/v3/businesses/search";
$BUSINESS_PATH = "/v3/businesses/";  // Business ID will come after slash.

// Defaults for our simple example.
$DEFAULT_TERM = "dinner";
$DEFAULT_LOCATION = "San Francisco, CA";
$SEARCH_LIMIT = 3;


/** 
* Makes a request to the Yelp API and returns the response
* 
* @param    $host    The domain host of the API 
* @param    $path    The path of the API after the domain.
* @param    $url_params    Array of query-string parameters.
* @return   The JSON response from the request      
*/
function request($host, $path, $url_params = array()) {
// Send Yelp API Call
try {
    $curl = curl_init();
    if (FALSE === $curl)
        throw new Exception('Failed to initialize');

    $url = $host . $path . "?" . http_build_query($url_params);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,  // Capture response.
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",  // Accept gzip/deflate/whatever.
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "authorization: Bearer " . $GLOBALS['API_KEY'],
            "cache-control: no-cache",
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    if (FALSE === $response)
        throw new Exception(curl_error($curl), curl_errno($curl));
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if (200 != $http_status)
        throw new Exception($response, $http_status);

    curl_close($curl);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);
        }

        return $response;
        }

  /**
  * Query the Search API by a search term and location 
  * 
  * @param    $term        The search term passed to the API 
  * @param    $location    The search location passed to the API 
  * @return   The JSON response from the request 
  */
  function search($term, $location) {
  $url_params = array();

  $url_params['term'] = $term;
  $url_params['location'] = $location;
  $url_params['limit'] = $GLOBALS['SEARCH_LIMIT'];

  return request($GLOBALS['API_HOST'], $GLOBALS['SEARCH_PATH'], $url_params);
  }

  /**
  * Query the Business API by business_id
  * 
  * @param    $business_id    The ID of the business to query
  * @return   The JSON response from the request 
  */
  function get_business($business_id) {
  $business_path = $GLOBALS['BUSINESS_PATH'] . urlencode($business_id);

  return request($GLOBALS['API_HOST'], $business_path);
  }

  /**
  * Queries the API by the input values from the user 
  * 
  * @param    $term        The search term to query
  * @param    $location    The location of the business to query
  */
  function query_api($term, $location) {     
  $response = json_decode(search($term, $location));
  $business_id = $response->businesses[0]->id;

  print sprintf(
    "%d businesses found, querying business info for the top result \"%s\"\n\n",         
    count($response->businesses),
    $business_id
  );

   $response = get_business($business_id);

    print sprintf("Result for business \"%s\" found:\n", $business_id);
    $pretty_response = json_encode(json_decode($response), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
    print "$pretty_response\n";
    }

   /**
   * User input is handled here 
   */
  $longopts  = array(
   "term::",
  "location::",
   );

   $options = getopt("", $longopts);

   $term = $options['term'] ?: $GLOBALS['DEFAULT_TERM'];
    $location = $options['location'] ?: $GLOBALS['DEFAULT_LOCATION'];

    query_api($term, $location);

    ?>
```

Comment: HTTP header names _should_ be treated case insensitive, but maybe they do want it spelled `Authorization` nevertheless. If that's not it, have you checked whether your API key value actually matches the expression from the error message?

Comment: Thank you were correct Authorization was case-sensitive "authorization: Bearer " . $GLOBALS['API_KEY']" changed to "authorization: bearer " . $GLOBALS['API_KEY']" Worked! Thank you!